# Greedy algorithm, numpy, matrix, explantation

Tags: python, numpy, greedy

Distance

from 0 to 1 is 1.0

from 1 to 2 is 3.0

from 0 to 2 is 2.0

```
D = [

     [ 0, 1.0, 2.0],
     [ 1.0, 0, 3.0],
     [ 2.0, 3.0, 0]
]
```

So I've got a matrix which looks like one above.

But I can't quite see why those measures are like the ones given at the top of my post?

How is distance from 0 to 1 is 1.0?

Comment: Maybe you are reading the index notation wrong? `D[0][1] = 1.0` etc - looking at the value's location in the array, not distance between values?

Comment: Its not my code. The distances are given in docs. I did not come up with that on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... this is a pre-loaded distance array.

Say for instance that point 0 is (5,0), point 1 is (4,0), and point 2 is (7,0). Then D is preloaded with inter-point distances, ie `D[from_point][to_point] = distance(from_point, to_point)`.

Then you can refer to the matrix rather than having to recalculate distances.

Comment: Ok, but which indexes from matrix are corresponding for let's say point id ?  Or it's points  ? Because diagonal is filled with zero's, and thats confusing for me

Comment: Oh I can see now. Thats because from 0 to 0 is 0... And from 2 to 2 is 0. Ok thanks mate. I think I get it now

Comment: So if you would like to have a bigger set of data, you would have to create array of NxN ? Where N is the number of our elements ?

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński: yes. You can save some space; the array is diagonally symmetric, so you only need to store items above the diagonal. So for N items you need to store N * (N - 1) / 2 values, which is still O(N**2).